# PowerBI Web: Connect to Oracle Cloud database

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I would like to know if it is possible in Power BI Web to retrieve data from an Oracle database hosted in Oracle Cloud. Or to any other database/cloud combo different that Azure SQL Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely achieve this.

There are connectors available for connecting powerbi desktop to oracle database.
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-oracle-database)
[Link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2VeqOMAda1o) 2

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know if there are connectors in the web version of Power BI.

Comment: Do it desktop version and upload report on web. You have your reports ready from oracle to powerbi